# How can this keyword access private members of class while object of class itself can not

Tags: java

I have a slight doubt with concept of this **keyword** let me show you an example through which i can explain it

```
public class InheritanceInJava
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
 A obj = new A(4,5);
 obj.num3 = 4; //using object to access private member of class which is not possible
 }
class A
{
 private int num1;
 private int num2;
 private int num3;
 A(int num1, int num2)
 {
 this.num1 = num1; //this keyword can access num1 in order initalize value 
 this.num2 = num2;
 }
}
```

Now as per the definition of this **keyword**, the this **keyword** can be used to refer to any member of the current object from within an instance Method or a constructor.

Since this is a reference to current object by which a method or constructor is invoked and since object of class itself can not access private members of class how can this  keyword access it ?.

If we look at above example :

this -> obj // this refer to current object which invokes constructor or method

and if, obj.num3 = 4 or obj.num1 = 6 is invalid.Then how this.num1 = num1 is valid ?

Comment: in simple terms, **this** represents the instance of current class. With **this** you do not need to create object to access any class member unless its static. As per your question your constructor ` A(int num1, int num2)` is assigning values to `num1,num2` with object its like insert values  to `num1,num2` and this has nothing to do with `this`(it is only for reference) and if you want to check then you must change the names of parameters of constructor and assign to current class instance without using this, will work fine

Answer (score 3):

The `private` access modifier limits access of those variables to inside the top-level class. Since you're calling `this` from inside the top-level class (as you must) you can access those variables.

I say "top-level" class instead of just class to cover the case of nested classes (an outer class can access the private fields of its inner class).

Comment: This isn't quite accurate. Private members can be accessed anywhere within the top-level class containing the member, so for example two nested classes can access each other's private members.

Comment: Well, yes, if you want to be more specific. I'll edit that in. @chrylis

Answer (score 0):

According to java docs  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html:

> The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that if the object is created with in the class then it can access the private data well from with in the class, private public restrictions doesn't apply to the members of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

The 'A' constructor is defined within the class in which you defined the private variables.  What your code is saying is:

"There is an 'A' class which has private variables(only 'A' can access them).  When constructed outside of the 'A' class, an 'A' object can give temporary permission to change those private variables, since this was defined in the constructor.  Any time after that, these private variables cannot be changed."

Comment: `an 'A' object can give temporary permission to change those private variables, since this was defined in the constructor. Any time after that, these private variables cannot be changed."` What?

Comment: When an 'A' object is created, it defines in the constructor that you can assign to its private variables.  So one way to think of it is: outside of the class you have the opportunity to define an 'A' object and, for one time only, change what the private variable is (for that object you created).

Comment: But the constructor isn't outside of the class?

Comment: The object that is created is outside of the 'A' class though.  Hence, the private variable cannot be assigned to.